# Decide the range of eigenvalues for $A+B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices on $\mathbb{C}$ such that all eigenvalues of $A$ lie in $[a,a']$ and all eigenvalues of $B$ lie in $[b,b']$. Show that all eigenvalues of $A+B$ lie in $[a+b,a'+b']$.

My thought: since $A$ is Hermitian, its eigenvalues are real. It should be unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix. But I don't know how to find unitary matrix to make $A,B$ simultaneously similar to diagonal matrix.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable if and only if they commute; this won't work in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A+B$ is also Hermitian, its eigenvalues are real too.There is an unitary matrix $U$ such that $A+B$ is similar to a diagonal matrix. Let $y=Ux$. Then
$$
\overline{x}^T(A+B)x=\overline{y}^T \overline{U}^T(A+B)Uy=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_{(A+B),k}|y|_i^2
$$
Since $\overline{y}^Ty=\overline{x}^Tx$, WLOG, assume $\overline{x}^Tx=1$. 
$$
\lambda_{(A+B)min}\leqslant \overline{x}^T(A+B)x\leqslant \lambda_{(A+B)max}\overline{y}^Ty=\lambda_{(A+B)max}\overline{x}^Tx=\lambda_{(A+B)max}\tag{1}
$$
Suppose $V,W$ be unitary matrices such that diagonalize $A,B$. So
$$
a\leqslant\lambda_{A,min}\leqslant\overline{x}^TAx=\overline{y}^T \overline{V}^TAVy\leqslant\lambda_{A,max}\leqslant a'\tag{2}
$$
And
$$
b\leqslant\lambda_{B,min}\leqslant\overline{x}^TBx=\overline{y}^T \overline{W}^TBWy\leqslant\lambda_{B,max}\leqslant b'\tag{3}
$$
Add $(2)$, $(3)$ and compare with $(1)$, we have
$$
a'+b'\geqslant\lambda_{(A+B)max} \hspace{4 mm} \text{and} \hspace{4 mm} 
a+b\leqslant\lambda_{(A+B)min}
$$

Comment: you only have guaranteed an inequality

Comment: @orangeskid That's exactly what was asked for.